# Android webview: throwing some token error. google.android.gms. something Plus webcookies not caching properly

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have a webview application. I actually refactored package name an old application. That one was actually using firebase messaging. I removed all references to the firebase in my version. But its still throwing an error.

```
    2019-07-15 23:34:49.191 13878-13878/? E/volley is: 0/
2019-07-16 02:24:51.997 30248-1014/? E/NetRec: [351] alcs.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rdg: 29503: 
        at avgq.b(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):3)
        at avgq.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):20)
        at alcs.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):1)
        at alcs.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):4)
        at alcr.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):9)
        at sdc.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):1)
        at bwt.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):5)
        at sdf.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):13)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):7)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):2)
     Caused by: rdg: 29503: 
        at rjf.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):4)
        at aodi.b(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):2)
        at aofv.a(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):6)
        at aaew.run(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):30)
        at bkng.run(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):2)
        at skq.b(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):37)
        at skq.run(:com.google.android.gms@17785040@17.7.85 (100700-253824076):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at sqo.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

App level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.storeuncle.studyapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

   // compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar"
}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Top level gradle

```
buildscript {  
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
      //  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The original pacakge name was com.xyz.appname. At first I changed just the appname. It worked fine. The I changed the folder name from xyz to something else. Thats when this error popped up. I have just one java file with all the code in it.

There are no errors in any on the lines in any files. manifest or gradle or any other files. The app crashed as soon as it launches. Can someboby please help me understand what should be causing this ? It would really make my day. Thank you.

**UPDATE On My Sufferings :-)** 
The app stopped crashing. But the error is still there. Also please have a look at my Code I have implemented for caching browser cookies. Cos this is also not working as expected either. The site works fine on all browsers. But in webview the cookies are inaccessible to the loaded pages on the first login. It only get the cookies after the second login.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    Toolbar toolbar;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    CookieManager cookieManager;

    String URLS = "https://xyz.co.in/zyx/panel/index.php";
    int is_url = 0;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1)
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());
        mWebView.clearCache(false);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        is_url = intent.getIntExtra("is_url", 0);
        if (is_url == 1) {
            URLS = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        }
        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            loadWebsite();
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadWebsite();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void loadWebsite() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(URLS);
        } else {
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

public class NewWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        String uid="";
        String pswd = "";
        String exp="";
        String usrnm = "";
        String cookies ="";
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if(url.contains("login")){
               // view.clearCache(true);
                //view.clearHistory();
                //view.clearFormData();
                Log.i("Listener", "Start");
            }

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
            try {

                if (cookies == null) {
                    return;
                }

                String[] splitCookies = cookies.split(";");
                for (String cookie : splitCookies) {
                    String[] cookieParts = cookie.split("=");
                    if (cookieParts.length > 0) {
                        String newCookie = cookieParts[0].trim() +
                                "=;expires=Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:01 UTC;";
                        cookieManager.setCookie(url, newCookie);
                    }
                }


                uid = getCookie(url, "user_id");
                    pswd = getCookie(url, "login_string");
                    usrnm = getCookie(url, "username");
                    exp = getCookie(url, "exp");
                    if (uid != null && !uid.isEmpty()) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString("user_id", uid);
                        editor.putString("login_string", pswd);
                        editor.putString("username", usrnm);
                        editor.putString("exp", exp);
                        //  Log.e("4444 ", ss.toString());
                        editor.commit();
                        Log.v(TAG, "cook page fin:" + cookies);
                    }


            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            if(url.contains("logout")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logout successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.clearCache(true);
                view.clearHistory();
                view.clearFormData();

                //sharedPref.edit().clear().apply();
                Log.i("Listener", "Finish");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url){
            Log.v(TAG, "onLoadResource url: " + url);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

        }
        public String getCookie(String siteName,String cookieName){
            String CookieValue = null;

            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);
            String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
            for (String ar1 : temp ){
                if(ar1.contains(cookieName)){
                    String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
                    CookieValue = temp1[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return CookieValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see logs of cookies as below

```
D/MainActivity: All the cookies in a string:PHPSESSID=p6puofnc250frclqh541cog5i6; user_id=4d236af1; username=Sachin; exp=2020-07-11; login_string=koko%40sert
V/MainActivity: cook page fin:PHPSESSID=p6puofnc250frclqh541cog5i6; user_id=4d236af1; username=Sachin; exp=2020-07-11; login_string=koko%40sert
```

Answer (score 0):

Even If there are no erros on It, please, share your code so we might have a better understanding of what is happening. 
More specifically, show the lines that throws the Exception.

Comment: I will post the code. But there is no line where I can see any error.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the package name you need to tell this to google. When you change folder name it changes your package name. Are you using google services? If yes then open your google account and update your app package name in it. After that download new google-services.json and replace it with your existing google-services.json in your project files under app folder.

Comment: I have removed all references to google from my code. The old project was using firebase. I dont want to use firebase.

Comment: It still needs updated google-services.json. Show me your gradle file

Comment: have you removed all the firebase libraries and google services

Comment: Yes. Atleast to my knowledge there is none.

Comment: try downloading the google-services.json It will solve your problem or try deleting that file

Comment: It is all beacuse of google-services.json have your pakage name in it

Comment: I had already deleted the file. Cos I didnt want firebase mesaging

Comment: That file is not only for firebase but It also support many google function such as maps and other cloud functions. Get it from google devloper account and you will be good to go.